# Find why a disk is at 100% utilization in linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, virtualization

I have a virtual machine running an application. After some time, its load starts increasing and the machine becomes unresponsive to commands.

After monitoring the disks usage, I found out a mounted SSD disk(AWS EBS General SSD) used by application is 100% busy with no read and writes from `nmon`.

Snapshot of `nmon` is:
[image]

Snapshot of `top` is:
[image]

I also tried using `iotop` to find the read and writes but there is no process doing a lot of read/writes.

Output of `iostat -x 2 5` is:
[image]

Besides this, All `ps` commands are getting stuck and enter into `D` state.

How to find the cause of 100% disk busy/utilized?

**Edit:**
The mounted partition is using XFS file system.

Comment: For VM’s with otherwise inexplicable performance issues it may be worthwhile to look at “stealtime” to see if  a VM is suffering from noisy neighbours. If that is the case ; simply power the VM down and restart it after a couple of minutes. Usually that will restart the VM on a *different* hypervisor; mitigating performance issues.

Comment: `top` output shows 0 steal time

Comment: In this case I would also stop the instance and copy its storage to a new storage volume, then restart the instance with the new volume.

Comment: The instance and/or volume is broken.  Nuke it and start again.

Comment: There are a number of *volume* metrics exposed by EBS volumes.  One of these may provide some useful insight, as may `dmesg`.   It is possible, even likely, that this condition reflects bad hardware or bad Nitro behavior that can only be mediated by moving to new equipment, but I'm a little disappointed by what feels like premature and speculative throwing up of hands in some of the previous comments.  It should not be the instance *and* the volume, but it may very well be one of them.  Trashing the whole thing doesn't provide much of a learning opportunity.

Comment: Often the output of `iotop -a` is more useful than just `iotop`. Sometimes I just use `grep ' D ' /proc/*/task/*/stat` to find processes doing I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Use next script for view - who read/wrete to disk:

```
#!/bin/sh

dmesg -c >/dev/null 2>&1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump

# Timeout
sleep 60

# Disable block dumping
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump


# Header
printf "%10s %15s %10s %10s %10s\n" CONUT COMMAND PID ACTION DEVICE

# Hide the eyes child! It gets ugly from here on
IFS="
"

for line in $(dmesg | awk '{if ( $3 ~ "READ" || $3 ~ "WRITE" ) { print  $2 " " $3 " " $7}}'| sort |uniq -c |sort -nr );
             do
                num=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
                command=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -re 's/\([[:digit:]]+\)://')
                pid=$(echo $line| awk -F'[()]' '{ print $2 }')
                action=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $3 }')
                device=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $4 }')

                printf "%10s %15s %10s %10s %10s\n" "$num" "$command" "$pid" "$action" "$device"
done
# EOF
```

Note: Depending on OS and dmesg output, you may have to change the fields in the "for line in" line"